# Why does resolv.conf have bad defaults and why is it always reordering the bad namesever first?

Tags: wireless

Have installed resolv.conf and it basically now adds the "good" ns to the list but only at the end.

127.0.0.53 is (for example) hanging and timing out on github. My laptop on same network has never had this problem and automatically seems to pick up on 192.158.1.1. Is this just luck?

Want to understand why the default appears to be so bad here? And why so many people need to manually intervene. What have they figured out on other systems?

EDIT/UPDATE:

```
$ ls -al /etc/resolv.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Nov 30 10:27 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf


$ time nslookup github.com 192.168.1.1
Server:     192.168.1.1
Address:    192.168.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   github.com
Address: 192.30.253.112
Name:   github.com
Address: 192.30.253.113


real    0m0.073s
user    0m0.006s
sys 0m0.005s

$ time nslookup github.com 127.0.0.53
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   github.com
Address: 192.30.253.112
Name:   github.com
Address: 192.30.253.113
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached


real    0m15.012s
user    0m0.008s
sys 0m0.004s

$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

Update 2 after some suggestions from chili555:

```
$ ls -al /etc/resolv.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 37 Dec  1 15:45 /etc/resolv.conf -> /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf

$ nslookup github.com
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

** server can't find github.com: SERVFAIL

$ nslookup github.com 192.168.1.1
Server:     192.168.1.1
Address:    192.168.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   github.com
Address: 192.30.253.112
Name:   github.com
Address: 192.30.253.113

$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

Comment: And https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1624320 seems relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual nameserver address in /etc/resolv.conf, 127.0.0.53 is not at all ‘bad.’ It reflects that dnsmasq is running on your system.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Dnsmasq

> A local DNS cache can speed up internet browsing because the user's
>   browser will not need to access a domain name server when it looks up
>   a domain name the computer has visited before.

The fact that DNS lookup is not working with this nameserver doesn’t usually mean that the nameserver and the underlying dnsmasq system are faulty. It usually suggests that the is another error in the resolvconf system.

Is /etc/resolv.conf a symbolic link? Check:

```
ls -al /etc/resolv.conf
```

To what does it link? Ideally, it will be /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf. If not, we’ll need to correct it.

As soon as we find more details about your system, we’ll make some amendments and I’ll further edit this partial answer.

**EDIT**: We see this in your edit:

```
$ ls -al /etc/resolv.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Nov 30 10:27 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
```

We suspect that the link should be as I posted above. Please try:

```
sudo rm -f /etc/resolv.conf
ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

Reboot and test.

Comment: Actually, 127.0.0.53 shows that systemd-resolve is running. Now dnsmasq may also be running, but it would put 127.0.0.1 in /etc/resolv.conf. One problem that shows up is when BOTH dnsmasq and systemd-resolve are running at the same time, and EITHER 127.0.0.53 OR 127.0.0.1 are in /etc/resolv.conf. There's a pref that needs changing with BOTH running. There's a little shenanigan with /etc/resolv.conf. In prior systems in pointed to  /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf, and people asked why it doesn't point to /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf... and it appears systemd-resolve isn't fully wired in yet.

Comment: @chili555 Have edited to add a bit more information. Interesting, I guess this suggests something is wrong with dnsmasq. Whatever I do, I seem to keep having the 127.0.053 be first in the resolve.conf list. This is pretty minor except that it means github "chugs" a bit everytime I use it, which is a lot. Will be learning more I guess until am at the bottom of it :)

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: So I'm basically now just following #38 of https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1624320 . The 127 nameserver no longer appears in /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: It certainly does in mine! Please try the fix I suggest above in my edit.

Comment: Yep, just saw your reply as I posted ... going to try your way and repost shortly!

Comment: @chili555 so I think I've set it up as you indicated, and am roughly back to where I was originally. The nslookup is failing on 127.0.0.53 if I understand it correctly.

Comment: Is *systemd* running? `ps aux | grep systemd` I needn't see the entire output, it should show 8-10 lines. Yes? Also, how about: `ps aux | grep systemd-resolved`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86477/discussion-between-mathtick-and-chili555).