# No connection being connected to working wireless network

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, internet

Apologies for the lack of formatting, I had to write this from my phone due to the current conditions.

**Summary**

I'm connected to a WiFi I'm certain that works. The problem is that I don't have any Internet connection.

**WiFi Icon**

The WiFi icon shows a question mark on top of an empty WiFi signal. I have read this problems in multiple forums and they recommend to deactivate connectivity checking. By doing so, the icon effectively disappears but I'm still without connection.

**nmcli d**

```
wlo1 WiFi connected sample_net
```

Is what shows after inputting such command. I also have docker connections but those are the default.

**logs app**

Opening the logs app, I can see that one of the most recent warnings under the "all" section is the following:

```
NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Deactivated successfully
```

It's followed by two previous logs of it trying to start up.

I have tried starting it through the console but the following error shows:

```
Unit NetworkManagerDispatcher.service was not found
```

**Wireless card**

14.3 Network controller: Intel corporation on WiFi 6 Ax201 (rev 20)

**ping -c3 8.8.8.8**

```
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2045ms
```

**ping -c3 [www.ubuntu.com](http://www.ubuntu.com)**

```
Failure in name resolution
```

**ls -al /etc/resolv.conf**

```
-rw-r--rr-- 1 root root
```

I've also tried deleting resolv.conf and just trying with just 8.8.8.8 as well but no luck with that either.

**cat /etc/resolv.conf**

```
nameserver 1.1.1.1
search polytechnique.fr
nameserver 129.104.30.41
nameserver 129.104.32.41
```

Please any help or tip is highly appreciated this has almost bricked my PC :,-)

Comment: Please edit your question to include the results of these terminal commands: `ping -c3 8.8.8.8` and: `ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com` and: `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: @chili555 Added. Anything ese that might help, tell me and I'll and it right away :)

Comment: Let's see: `cat /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: @chili555 added. I have a custom config for a tunneled TLS. I have also tried with no file

Comment: Please see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097382/why-does-resolv-conf-have-bad-defaults-and-why-is-it-always-reordering-the-bad-n/1097457#1097457 resolv.conf is supposed to be a symbolic link. I suggest setting your custom nameserver details in Network Manager.