# Ubuntu 22.04 resolv.conf/DNS problem, cannot access internet

Tags: internet, dns, resolv.conf

My Ubuntu 22.04 computer was working fine.  Somehow it crashed, upon reboot, I could not access the internet.  Network works fine, able to access other network devices.  I traced the issue to what I think is DNS and did the following;

```
rm -f /etc/resolv.conf

vim /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
--> add Google name server 8.8.8.8

ln -s /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

Internet works but when I restart, my changes are deleted.

My computer used to use the DNS from my router without having to add the Google DNS.  How do I make this a permanent fix?  Everytime I make this change, it is overwritten on restart, I don't know what service is doing this.

Comment: Please try the sequence here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097382/why-does-resolv-conf-have-bad-defaults-and-why-is-it-always-reordering-the-bad-n/1097457#1097457 Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: My 22.04 laptop started this y'day p.m. systemd-resolvd is running. resolv.conf (symlink to /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf) has [phone kbd is really difficult!] nameserver 127.0.0.53<newline>options edns0 trust-ad<newline>search .<newline><EOF>

Comment: [Cont.] /var/log/syslog has many "[timestsmp] systemd-resolvd ... Using degraded feature set TCP instead of UDP for DNS server ::1." alrernating with "... set UDP instead of TCP..."

Comment: [cont.] "nslookup github.com 192.168.68.1" succeeds. "nslookup github.com" fails; "nslookup github.com 127.0.0.53" fails (192.168.68.1 is wifi IP addr)

Comment: workaround so I can type on real machine: sudo mv /etc/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf; sudo vi /etc/resolv.conf <insert nameserver 192.168.68.1>:wq;

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with ubuntu vm in VirutalBox. I have found NAT Networks section empty, under Tools - Network Manager. I have added one with all defaults at which stage it was getting a NAT dhcp ip address. This has resolved the issue.